# How to calculate percentage of sum hash value in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have static json file which contains:

```
{
  "homes": {
    "person_a": "windows+tables",
    "person_b": "lights+tables",
    "person_c": "doors+curtains"
 }
}
```

The application should, for each request, calculate quotes for the 3 insurers. The business requirement is as follows:

The quote is a 10% of the rate if 2 covers are matched or 20% if just 1 cover is matched and that is the biggest requested, 25% if it is the second biggest or 30% if is the third.

the request from user is as follow

```
{:curtains=>20, :tables=>30, :windows=>50}
```

The system should not return a quote if the value is zero(0)

The application will then calculate the following quotes:

```
person_a: 8 (10% of 80 (two matches on windows and tables))
person_b: 7.5 (25% of 30 (one match on contents, the 2nd biggest cover))
insurer_c: 6 (30% of 20 (one match on curtains, the 3rd biggest cover)
```

This is my solution:

```
require_relative './rules'

module Coverage
  class CalculateQuotes
    def initialize(quotes)
      @quotes = quotes
    end

    def get_rates
      result = []
      @insurer = Coverage::Rules.parse_file ## which will give {
                                        #"insurer_rates": {
                                       #"person_a": "windows+tables",
                                       # "person_b": "lights+tables",
                                       #"person_c": "doors+curtains"
                                      # }}
      @insurer[:insurer_rates].each do |k, v|
        @match_covers = match_cover(v.split("+"))
        result << [k, calculate_rate ]
      end
    end

    def match_cover(covers)
      covers = covers.map { |x| x.to_sym }
      @quotes.select { |k,v| covers.include?(k) }
    end

    def calculate_rate
      premium    = 0.0
      persentage = get_percentage_by_match_covers
      @match_covers.values.each do |v|
        premium += v * persentage
      end
      premium == 0 ? nil : premium
    end

    def get_percentage_by_match_covers
      if @match_covers.size == 2
        0.1
      elsif @match_covers.size == 1
        only_1_match_covers
      else
        0
      end
    end

    def only_1_match_covers
      index = position_of_customer_request
      case index
      when 0
        0.2
      when 1
        0.25
      when 2
        0.3
      else
        raise StandardError
      end
    end

    def position_of_customer_request
      (@quotes.to_a.reverse).index(@match_covers.to_a.flatten)
    end
  end
end


request = {:windows=>50, :contents=>30, :engine=>20}

Coverage::CalculateQuotes.new(request).get_rates
```

Please help me on How can I make it better calculation and code with SOLID ruby principles??

Comment: Hi Max. You haven't asked a question or demonstrated a problem. If you'd like to chat about an assignment or homework you might want to see if a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is a more appropriate place.

Comment: @coreyward how should I use a chat room  for any queries to be asked

Comment: max, I would encourage you to edit the question, addressing concerns that have been expressed. If you do there's a good chance the hold would be lifted. Note that many questions on SO are homework problems. There's no prohibition on that, but when the question is a homework problem the asker is expected to describe efforts they have made to solve the problem (with or without code). That's not an issue here; even if you are working on a homework problem you certainly have demonstrated that you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
double_quote_rate = 0.1
single_quote_rate = [0.3, 0.25, 0.2]
request = {:curtains=>20, :tables=>30, :windows=>50}
```

**Code**

The key is to create a hash that maps sets of products into their computed values.

The first step is to create the key-value pairs where the key is a set containing a single product:

```
require 'set'

h = single_quote_rate.zip(request.sort_by(&:last)).
      each_with_object({}) { |(rate, (product, score)),h|
        h[[product].to_set] = rate*score }
  #=> {#<Set: {:curtains}>=>6.0, #<Set: {:tables}>=>7.5,
  #    #<Set: {:windows}>=>10.0}
```

Note that the values in `single_quote_rate` are ordered largest to smallest. The intermediate calculation is as follows:

```
single_quote_rate.zip(request.sort_by(&:last))
  #=> [[0.3, [:curtains, 20]], [0.25, [:tables, 30]],
  #    [0.2, [:windows, 50]]]
```

Now add all combinations of two products:

```
request.to_a.combination(2).each { |(product1, score1),(product2,score2)|
  h[[product1,product2].to_set] = double_quote_rate*(score1+score2) }

h #=> {#<Set: {:curtains}>=>6.0,
  #    #<Set: {:tables}>=>7.5,
  #    #<Set: {:windows}>=>10.0,
  #    #<Set: {:curtains, :tables}>=>5.0,
  #    #<Set: {:curtains, :windows}>=>7.0,
  #    #<Set: {:tables, :windows}>=>8.0}
```

Here the first calculation is as follows:

```
enum = request.to_a.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:curtains, 20], [:tables, 30],
  #                  [:windows, 50]]:combination(2)>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the three elements (arrays) that will be passed to the block.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[:curtains, 20], [:tables, 30]],
  #    [[:curtains, 20], [:windows, 50]],
  #    [[:tables, 30], [:windows, 50]]]
```

The block variables are assigned as follows:

```
(product1, score1),(product2,score2) = enum.next
  #=> [[:curtains, 20], [:tables, 30]] 
product1
  #=> :curtains 
score1
  #=> 20 
product2
  #=> :tables 
score2
  #=> 30
```

Breaking up arrays into their component elements is called [array decompostion](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

For convenience assign the keys of `request` to a variable:

```
keys = request.keys
  #=> [:curtains, :tables, :windows]
```

**Example**

```
hash = { "homes": { "person_a": "windows+tables",
                    "person_b": "lights+tables",
                    "person_c": "doors+curtains" } }
```

```
hash[:"homes"].transform_values do |s|
  h[s.split('+').map(&:to_sym).select { |s| keys.include?(s) }.to_set]
end
  #=> {:person_a=>8.0, :person_b=>7.5, :person_c=>6.0}
```

An example calculation of the key to use to obtain the desired value of `h` is as follows:

```
s = "lights+tables"
a = s.split('+')
  #=> ["lights", "tables"] 
b = a.map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:lights, :tables] 
c = b.select { |s| keys.include?(s) }
  #=> [:tables] 
d = c.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {:tables}> 
h[d]
  #=> 7.5
```